# Static files give ever changing checksum value on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, filesystems, corruption

When I cksum large files (150MB) they will often report different checksums on each call.

```
$ cksum test3
1233504235 170213376 test3
$ cksum test3
825031809 170213376 test3
$ cksum test3
189847968 170213376 test3
$ cksum test3
1089532177 170213376 test3
```

This happens consistently in **/dev/shm** but I've seen it in disk based ext3 filesystems as well.

I am confident the files are **not** being written to at the time of the checks.

It's been an issue since I upgraded from Debian 6 32bit to 7 32bit
but I had similar issues on 64bit Debian 6 (reinstalled 32bit to cure the problem).

The memory has passed multiple Memtest86+ runs.
The are no indications of filesystem corruption.

Could there be a BIOS setting; kernel parameter or filesystem flag that I need to set.

filesystem flags are:

```
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=2040740k)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/b236be25-6fe1-49f6-83a3-d295643666a4 on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered)
```

This is driving me nuts as my data files keep getting corrupted and I can't use the system.

**UPDATE**

Booting off the previous kernel (2.6.32) stops the file corruptions. It also reduces the memory from 4GB to 3GB even tho both kernels report 'getconf LONG_BIT' as 32

Comment: Curious, what do you get with `md5`?

Comment: Can you create a dummy file in the same folder that exhibits the same behaviour? What is your kernel version? Have you tried mounting the disk on a different system?

Comment: I do get the same problem when using md5sum.

Comment: Kernel is SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1. I haven't tried moving the disk but /dev/shm is created in memory after each reboot and reboots do not resolve the problem.

Comment: Any large file in /dev/shm exhibits the same behaviour. I've tried several different file types.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the file system cache? `su root -c "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"` What happens, when you create a ramdisk, and you hash a file on it?

Comment: @David Thanks for the tip on clearing the caches but unfortunately it made no difference to the problem. Strangely the problem didn't seem to manifest on a small (300MB) ramdisk created using tmpfs (the same as /dev/shm).

Comment: I'm still not entirely sold on this not being caused by an userspace program rather than kernel-bug/faulty hardware. For faulty hardware, given that this is tmpfs, you'd be seeing either memory corruption, or in-flight corruption, which memtest should have caught, I'd also have expected kernel oopses if memory is randomly mangled(It'd be weird if it's isolated only to bodies of files on tmpfs) Unless you've already tried, I'd suggest looking into inotify, and have inotify watches on the files watching for modifications, when you see the files change, and lsof for seeing if the files are opened

Answer (score 4):

I suggest inspecting the file itself and seeing if it is actually valid and consistent.

`cksum` computes a CRC.  There is a purpose-specific instruction for this on modern x86 CPUs which may or may not be in use here; in that case it is possible that the CPU might be faulty, and also possible that this fault might not show up anywhere else.  Consider ensuring your microcode is up to date or trying to checksum the file using another utility that doesn't do CRC (`md5sum` comes to mind), or testing this on another computer.

Comment: I do have a validator for the file structure and that also shows the problem. However I thought using cksum for my examples would be better. It might be a CPU fault but md5sum also shows the same problem as does sum. I have tested this on another Debian 7 system and I do not get this issue.

Comment: It is most likely some kind of obscure hardware or firmware issue.

Comment: I've updated the firmware to the latest version but this has made no difference.

Comment: Well, you likely have your answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The files under `/dev` are special. In particular, `/dev/shm` is the mountpoint for shared memory stuff, see `shm_overview(7)`. No wonder it changes "behind your back". Make *sure* your mysteriously changing files aren't e.g. a database of some sort or something else that changes with normal operations.